# Object.Reduce not returning the right value

Tags: javascript

I need to sum all valorReal values which are inside an array demonstrativo inside the object demonstrativoIr, there are 25 objects with valorReal values around 300, and the returning sum value is 416. Not sure what im doing wrong here

this is the reduce

```
.subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.movimento = data.reduce((a,b)=> ({
        ...a,
        dataMovimento: a.dataMovimento,
        valor: a.valor + b.valor,
        valorReal: a.demonstrativoIr.demonstrativo[0].valorReal + b.demonstrativoIr.demonstrativo[0].valorReal 
      }))
```

[image: This is the original data result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just sum up the `valorReal` of the last two elements (`a` and `b` at the last iteration, everything before will be ignored). You could instead take the `valorReal` inside the accumulator:

```
  this.movimento = data.reduce((acc, el) => ({
    ...acc,
    valor: acc.valor + el.valor,
    // Take the accumulated value here:
    valorReal: acc.valorReal + el.demonstrativoIr.demonstrativo[0].valorReal 
  // Ensure it is 0 and not undefined at the first iteration:
  }), {valor: 0, valorReal: 0});
```

Comment: thanks man, the math was actually fine , but the acc and el denomination gave me a better understading of how it works, and i wasnt a aware of the overloard with initial values. Have a nice day

Comment: @daniel glad to help :)